# pyaudio installation problem command error occured

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I've been trying to install pyaudio module for speech recognition through a microphone but i couldn't and i have no idea what this error says to me. I'd be very happy if someone helps me
here is the error code (it is the same error without a virtual environment btw, i am using visual studio code):

.

(venv) PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding\Python\speech> pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\user\desktop\coding\python\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3_xztlm\pyaudio_ed19c843927e4d4a9d6303dc8a6e860a\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3_xztlm\pyaudio_ed19c843927e4d4a9d6303dc8a6e860a\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize,
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5sg_cu_f\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\desktop\coding\python\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyaudio'
cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3_xztlm\pyaudio_ed19c843927e4d4a9d6303dc8a6e860a
Complete output (9 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\desktop\coding\python\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3_xztlm\pyaudio_ed19c843927e4d4a9d6303dc8a6e860a\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3_xztlm\pyaudio_ed19c843927e4d4a9d6303dc8a6e860a\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code =
f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5sg_cu_f\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\desktop\coding\python\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.

I have installed the Visual Studio C++
Nothing changed.
Thx.

Comment: It seems like you might have installed the wrong version. 14.0 apparently means you have to install the 2015 redistributable. If you go to Apps & features in Windows, you should be able to find an entry where when you click it, you see a version number like 14.xx.xxxx; if not then you need to install the correct version.

Comment: thx for your reply. i did tried to install it again. Essentially nothing changed. Tho it does not ask me to install c++ or higher. all the other error codes are there still.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thx davis, i literally uninstalled everything and it worked after reinstall